# Is this worst-case analysis correct?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Here is the code:

```
int Outcome = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
    for (int j = i+2; j = 0; j--)  
        Outcome += i*j;
```

Here's my analysis.  Since the first line is an assignment statement, this takes exactly one time unit, O(1).  The breakdown for line 2 is : 1 + N + N = 2N + 2.  With line 3,
since the loop’s content is a single operation, the loop and its block perform i+1 operations.  This is also a nested for loop.  Finally, line 4 takes exactly one time unit to execute.  Therefore, the big-Oh notation for this code in terms of N is O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Sounds correct to me. Good job!

Comment: `x^2` is quadratic..which is a polynomial on `x` of order `2`. You can say your complexity is `O(i*j)` and `j=O(i)`, therefore you have `O(n^2)`..whenever you have a nested loop, it is usually `O(n^2)` :)

Comment: See [this dependent nested loop complexity](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence) question on CS.

Comment: Presumably that third line should say `j >= 0`?

Answer (score 1):

To be exact: As you say, line 4 is 1 operation. For a specific `i`, you execute the inner loop `i+3` times. Therefore, your total number of operations is

```
sum(0 <= i <= N-1 : i+3) 
    = 3N + sum(0 <= i <= N-1 : i) 
    = 3N + N(N-1) / 2
    = N^2/2 + 5N/2
    = O(N^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct about the final efficiency class, but it is possible to be more rigorous. The first thing is that you usually just pick the most expensive basic operation to count for your analysis. In this case it would likely be the multiplication in the innermost loop, which is executed once per iteration. So how many times is it called? On the first iteration of the outermost loop, the inner loop will iterate twice. On the second outer iteration, it will be three times, and similarly up to N+2 (I'm assuming the inner loop condition is meant to be `j >= 0`). So that leaves us with the following summation:

```
sum(2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ..., N+2)
= sum(1, 2, 3, 4 ..., N+2) - 1
= (N+2)(N+3)/2 - 1
```

Which is in O(N²) (and actually since you have this specific result that will always be the same you can say it's in ϴ(N²)).